# Storing not predefined user metadata architecture

Tags: database-design, architecture

Till now we were using MySQL DB for storing user metadata like birthday, anniversary etc. But now with increasing number of customers, the number of these metadata is increasing and starting to become exclusive for different customers (for example, one customer wanted his medical expiry date to be stored as user metadata).

Can someone please guide me the best possible architectural solution for this? Should we move to NoSQL DB? Is there a way we can handle with relational DB?

Comment: Can you please include some sample data?

Comment: sample data as in?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague, because we can't see exactly _what_ metadata you have to store.  MySQL, and SQL in general, can certainly handle storing information as key value pairs.  Whether that makes sense over something like NoSQL depends on your data and expected use of that data.

Comment: use metadata like birthdays, date of joining, location, designation, department, role_id --> these are the current columns in our MySQL DB for user metadata corresponding to a userId

Now we have an increasing number of user metadata demanded by our customers like storing medical expiry, license number etc

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2009/11/19/what-is-so-bad-about-eav-anyway

Comment: @Jordan An easy solution could be using a column for storing these values as JSON (provided you don't have to search the table based on these metadata values).